# Realm.js - How to addListener to a single object and update UI

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a list of objects displayed in a list. I get the object in this way

```
const elements = realm
      .objects("Element").sorted("name", false);
```

Then I display those elements in a list and when I tap on an element of the list I open a new "scene" (I use react-native-router-flux) and send the object as props. Now when I update the object via Realm Studio I can't see the UI updates.

Is there anything like objects.addListener that I can use for listening to the single object changes? Or, How can I update the second view from the first (the one when I listen for changes at the collection)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Realm has both collection notifications for watching multiple objects or object-level notifications for watching a single object. It's in the documentation under [Object Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications) that's the Swift version but it's the same concept throughout. Was there something more?

Comment: I think that object notification in not yet supported for the javascript API.

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/763

Comment: Well that's disappointing - two years and no progress? That being said, if you know the specific objectId, you can add a collection listener for just that object  I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's possible to use listeners also on single objects.

Simply use

```
object.addListener((obect)=>{
    // do updates
})
```